# How to handle deploy process of capistrano if it fails on a machine in case of multiserver deployment?

Tags: capistrano

I am trying to use capistrano in which i have 4 application servers. I am not sure about the behaviour of capistrano in case deploy fail on one machine. If the network connection is disconnected for a machine then the processes on all the machines go on interrupted sleep and does not notify anything. Please let me know how to trac such issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano has its own transaction management, if it fails on any of the machine then the deploy:rollback is called and all the machines always remain in same valid state.